# How to add multiple custom ticks to seaborn boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, xticks

I generated a boxplot using seaborn. On the x axis, I would like to have, both the number of days (20, 25, 32) and the actual dates they refer to (2022-05-08, 2022-05-13, 2022-05-20).
I found a potential solution at the following link [add custom tick with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471424/add-custom-tick-with-matplotlib). I'm trying to adapt it to my problem but I could only get the number of days or the dates, not both.
I really would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance for your time.
Please, find below my code and the desired output.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'nb_days':[20,20,20,25,25,20,32,32,25,32,32],
             'Dates':['2022-05-08','2022-05-08','2022-05-08','2022-05-13','2022-05-13','2022-05-08','2022-05-20','2022-05-20','2022-05-13','2022-05-20','2022-05-20'],
             'score':[3,3.5,3.4,2,2.2,3,5,5.2,4,4.3,5]})

df['Dates'] = df['Dates'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
tick_label = dict(zip(df['nb_days'],df['Dates'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))) #My custom xtick label

#Plot
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
ax = sns.boxplot(x='nb_days',y='score',data=df,color=None)
# iterate over boxes to change color
for i,box in enumerate(ax.artists):
    box.set_edgecolor('red')
    box.set_facecolor('white')

sns.stripplot(x='nb_days',y='score',data=df,color='black')
ticks = sorted(df['nb_days'].unique())
labels = [tick_label.get(t, ticks[i]) for i,t in enumerate(ticks)]
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Here is the desired output.

[image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by adding these lines in place of `ax.set_xticklabels(labels)`

```
new_labels=["{}\n{}".format(a_, b_) for a_, b_ in zip(ticks, labels)]
ax.set_xticklabels(new_labels)
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns

    df = pd.DataFrame({'nb_days':[20,20,20,25,25,20,32,32,25,32,32],
                'Dates':['2022-05-08','2022-05-08','2022-05-08','2022-05-13','2022-05-13','2022-05-08','2022-05-20','2022-05-20','2022-05-13','2022-05-20','2022-05-20'],
                'score':[3,3.5,3.4,2,2.2,3,5,5.2,4,4.3,5]})

    df['Dates'] = df['Dates'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
    tick_label = dict(zip(df['nb_days'],df['Dates'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))) #My custom xtick label

    #Plot
    fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
    ax = sns.boxplot(x='nb_days',y='score',data=df,color=None)
    # iterate over boxes to change color
    for i,box in enumerate(ax.artists):
        box.set_edgecolor('red')
        box.set_facecolor('white')

    sns.stripplot(x='nb_days',y='score',data=df,color='black')
    ticks = sorted(df['nb_days'].unique())
    labels = ["{}\n".format(t)+tick_label.get(t, ticks[i]) for i, t in enumerate(ticks)]
    ax.set_xticklabels(labels)

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

[image]